# Android Studio - AVD doesn't recognize gestures (cant unlock emulator)

Tags: java, android, emulation, gesture, android-virtual-device

I just started learning to program for android and sadly after making one program (Hello World) I have already ran into an issue.  The gesture for "Swipe to Unlock" or for the camera are not functioning.  I can bypass it on the stock emulator because it shows a notification i can click that will skip the screen, however i would much rather just figure out a solution, i have searched around on Google and StackOverflow to no avail... maybe someone can help out.

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Answer (score 11):

ok solved! for those that might have the same problem, just press f2

Comment: Side note, if this doesn't work for you, try opening the camera. For me, it generated an error, then unlocked the phone.

Answer (score 7):

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

I had the same issue and grew tired of it, this always worked.

Comment: The only method that works reliably in my case.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

AVD_WXGA_TABLET emulator.
Android v 7

F2 does nothing.
Dragging with left-down mouse tries to do a swipe up but bounces back down when I release the mouse.
I've tried fast and slow, release on the virtual device or off it.  Short and long strokes.  You name it...

The f'ing thing won't unlock.  And for all the keystrokes available in the tool pallet including fingerprints, there is no simple swipe-left/up/down/right.  You'd think they would have had cntrol-alt-arrow for that out of sheer common sense or as the result of the developer trying to use it.

Comment: It's 2019 and I have the same issue with Pixel 2 API 27 emulator.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just restarted the simulator by holding down the "Power" button in the simulator menu for a couple of seconds and then choosing "Restart." I was able to unlock the simulator easily after that.

Answer (score 1):

On mac you can keep holding the command key and then do the swipe gesture with the mouse or trackpad of your computer.

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVvll.gif)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is actually the answer that helped me.  seemed like no matter what else I did, trying to swipe on the screen with my mouse would just pop open a little context menu to edit settings, widgets and wallpapers.  holding control while swiping, even though that's meant to be used for multitouch, seems to have reset things.  now I can swipe normally again.  at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using one of two ways

- Swipe up from top section of screen
- Swipe up from bottom section of screen i.e. just above the navigation buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly which step solved it, maybe all, but these were my steps

- Use the SDK manager to update to the latest version of the emulator
- Turn off the emulator (hold the power button and select Power Off)
- Close Android Studio
- Reopen Android Studio
- Launch the emulator from the AVD manager